# Converting Java ByteBuffer saved to sqlite to Python native data

Tags: python, java, binary, byte, bytebuffer

I am trying to access a database column for the game Project Zomboid.

There is a table named NetworkPlayers which has a binary BLOB data column. An example of which contents is below:

```
\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00E\xd4\x94HE\xaa\x13\xe5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x06hotbar\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x01?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04Back\x01@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\rSmallBeltLeft\x01@\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0eSmallBeltRight\x01@\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0bHolsterLeft\x01@\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cHolsterRight\x00\x00\x0fstrengthUpTimer\x01\xc0\xe8h\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0bstrengthMod\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0efitnessUpTimer\x01\xc0\xe8V\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\nfitnessMod\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07Fav:Axe\x01@N\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02u\x00\x07Raleigh\x00\x06Runyon\x00\x04Kate\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\nparkranger\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x03Axe\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08Strength\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x0fPlantScavenging\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x08Woodwork\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08Trapping\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x07Fitness\x00\x00\x00\x03>\xa9\x85Q\xa9\x85Q\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\xff\x00\x00\x00\nLongBraids\x12l$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cl\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x0c\x18\x0c\x0c\x0c\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xa9\x85Q\xa9\x85Q\x00\x04none\x01\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x98\x06]\x05Y\x85KlH\x0b\x00"Base.Tshirt_Profession_RangerBrown\x00\x00\x00\x1dTshirt_Profession_RangerBrown\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00))\xb1m\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x1e\x17\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00(\x00\xe3\xc6\xac\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16@\xe6\xe6\xe6A\xe6\xe6\xe6\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00Y\x06\xa9\x05X,\x03\x8aH\x0b\x00\x0fBase.Socks_Long\x00\x00\x00\nSocks_Long&-,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12?\xc8\xc8\xca\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00y\x02\x90\x05\x1f5\xa5\xceH\r\x00\x14Base.Trousers_Ranger\x00\x00\x00\x0fTrousers_Ranger\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x96\xff\x98\x96\x87\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16@z\xfa\xfbB\x84\x14\x15\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00]\x03\x92\x05\x01t\xbf\xbeH\x0b\x00\x11Base.Shoes_Random\x00\x00\x00\x0cShoes_Random\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14@UUVCB%\xfe\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc6\x04W\x06\x03\x03\n-@\x02\x00 \x08\x00\x19Raleigh Runyon\'s Key Ring\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07KeyRing\x01\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x03}\x08iE\x10Y@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\xbf\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x03z\x08\x14\xfb1\x1e@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x010\xc1[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x03z\x08(~F\x86@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x0e\x97C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00#\x04\xb0\x08\tM\x08\xee@\x02\x80 \x08\x00\x08Taxi Key\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x04\x02\xe8\x84\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xd1\x04W\x06\tV/C@\x02\x00 \x08\x00\x1bBranden Shanahan\'s Key Ring\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07KeyRing\x01\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x03p\x08t>\xd5\xf8@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03P\xf2L\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x03p\x08jQ\xcd\'@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\xbf\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00,\x04\xb0\x08?\xa6\xca\xdf@\x02\x00 \x08\x00\x15Franklin Valuline Key\x00\x00\x00\x00\x023\xdf\xcd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x03~\x08j\\>\x05@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02>i\xce\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x008\x07\xc9\x05F\x87\xfb\x8bH\x0b\x00\nBase.Belt2\x00\x00\x00\x04Belt\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xbf\x80\x00\x00k\x05\xc4\x8a\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00O\x05\xd9\x019\x8f4\x86@\x02\x1c \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x04Back\x00\x1bBig Weapon On Back with Bag\x00\x04\x02\x19?\x99\x99\x9a?L\xcc\xcd@\x00\x00\x00?8Q\xec?\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00~\x04\xb5\x06G\xa5s\x0cH\r\x00\x15Base.Bag_BigHikingBag\x00\x00\x00\x10Bag_BigHikingBag\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x10Bag_BigHikingBag\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x0b\x05GC\xe50L\x04\r\x00\x17Base.HoodieUP_WhiteTINT\x00\x00\x00\x12HoodieUP_WhiteTINTMUI\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x86b|\xff\x00\x00\xc5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\r\x00\x12\x1e\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16@\x8222B\x1eno\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x07\xa4\x05\n\xb5Q\xe7H\x0b\x00\x15Base.Shoes_BlackBoots\x00\x00\x00\x10Shoes_BlackBoots\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00I\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x80 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x95\x16A\x95\x05\x06B\xc8\x00\x00\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00I\x00\xe6\x05k\xa7\x11OH\x0b\x00\x12Base.HolsterDouble\x00\x00\x00\rHolsterDouble\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x04\x04z\x8f\x97\xbe@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.t\x08\xe6\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x07{\x04H\xe0\xf0\x89@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00%\x03\x9e\x01.k1ID\x02\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x19?Y\x99\x9a>\x99\x99\x9a?333?&ff\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x05D\x00#cD\\@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00$\x06\x01\x01N\x9e,\x86@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x19?\x8c\xcc\xcd?\x00\x00\x00?\x80\x00\x00?+\x85\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x04\x10\x00\x7f!R1@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x15\x07\xdd\x04bZ\xd5rB\x18\x02\x00 \x80?\x05\x1e\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04.\x0c"\xc3\x97\xe5H\r\x00!Base.WristWatch_Left_DigitalBlack\x00\x00\x00\x1cWristWatch_Left_DigitalBlack\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00(\x00\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x11\x03\xb8\x03\x05\xa0\xfb\xd0@\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x002\x00\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x80\x00\x006\xab$\xdc?L\xcc\xcc>\xa8m@?\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>0\xc2\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00=\xa4\xfaV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00A\x8a\x1a\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\x14q"\x00\xbf\x81lh\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x80\x00\x00\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01B\x14\x00\x00@\x04*\x91\xbf\x80\x00\x00=\xe2D\x007\xd4q/\x00\x00\x00\x00?1\x85Q\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00B\x0c\x90\xcaB\x04\xb0r\xbd\x14\x01i>\x07\xc2g;\x18\xb7\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x01B\x0c\x90\xcaB\x04\xb0r\xbd\x14\x01i>\x07\xc2g;\x18\xb7\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x02B\x0c\xa9\xacB\x04\xe26\xbd\x8cr\xbe>\x1eb\xcd;r\x82\x9a\x00\x00\x00\x03B\x0c\xa9\xacB\x04\xe26\xbd\x8cr\xbe>\x1eb\xcd;r\x82\x9a\x00\x00\x00\x04B\x0c\xe4\xf2B\x05X\xc2\xbd\x89\xcf6>@Sg;\xd9\x19\xf6\x00\x00\x00\x05B\x0c\xe4\xf2B\x05X\xc2\xbd\x89\xcf6>@Sg;\xd9\x19\xf6\x00\x00\x00\x06B\x14q"B\x05\xeb\x8c\xbe\xd3\xed\xf1>bD\x00<0\xc1\xb5\x00\x00\x00\x07B\r\x1f|B\x05\xcd\xd6\xbe\x8c]\xfd>\\\x9b\xe7<#\xd4\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x08B\r\x1f|B\x05\xcd\xd6\xbe*\xbd\xd6>\\\x9b\xe7<#\xd4\x1f\x00\x00\x00\tB\r(RB\x05\xdf\x81\xbd\xa0\xf8\xf3>`\x00\xc3<+\x81\xc0\x00\x00\x00\nB\x0c\xefjB\x05m\xb2\xbd\xa9n\x1c>@Sg;\xd9\x19\xf6\x00\x00\x00\x0bB\x0c\xc2\xc6B\x05\x14j\xbd\xf9s\xce>/[\x19;\xa4\x8e\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0cB\x0c\xc2\xc6B\x05\x14j\xbd\xf9s\xce>/[\x19;\xa4\x8e\x0e\x00\x00\x00\rB\x0c\x9atB\x04\xc3\xc6\xbd\x82Z\xbe>\rj\x80;,\x9d+\x00\x00\x00\x0eB\x0c\x9atB\x04\xc3\xc6\xbd\x82Z\xbe>\rj\x80;,\x9d+\x00\x00\x00\x0fB\x0c\x7f\x7fB\x04\x8d\xdc\xbc\x91\xcef=\xe2D\x00:\xb0\xc1\xb5\x00\x00\x00\x10B\x0c\x7f\x7fB\x04\x8d\xdc\xbc\x91\xcef=\xe2D\x00:\xb0\xc1\xb5\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\nHighThirst\x00\x0bConspicuous\x00\x0eHeartyAppitite\x00\x0bWeakStomach\x00\x06Clumsy\x00\x0cShortSighted\x00\x0cSundayDriver\x00\x08Dextrous\x00\tOrganized\x00\x08Athletic\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x07CookingBz\x00\x00\x00\x03AxeCEq\xcf\x00\x0fPlantScavengingCa\x00\x00\x00\x08StrengthG\x13u\x00\x00\x0bMaintenanceA\x00\x00\x00\x00\tSprintingA0\x00\x00\x00\x08WoodworkB\x96\x00\x00\x00\x08TrappingCa\x00\x00\x00\x07FitnessH\xa4\xd6\xe0\x00\x06Nimble?\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x03Axe\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x08Trapping\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x08Woodwork\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x07Fitness\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x0fPlantScavenging\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x08Strength\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x0fMake Stick Trap\x00\x0fMake Snare Trap\x00\x15Make Wooden Cage Trap\x00\rMake Trap Box\x00\x0eMake Cage Trap\x00\x10Make Metal Walls\x00\x0fMake Metal Roof\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@1\xbe\xe6}\xcd\x92\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\t\x00\tBeltExtra\x00\x0c\x00\x04Belt\x00\x06\x00\x06Tshirt\x00\x00\x00\tLeftWrist\x00\x15\x00\x05Socks\x00\x01\x00\x05Pants\x00\x02\x00\nSweaterHat\x00\n\x00\x05Shoes\x00\x0b\x00\x04Back\x00\t\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc4\x15\xc7\xf1\xc1\xdf\x85W\xc2E\xbf\x0f\xc3\x19\x99\xc9B\x9f\xff\xdb\x00\x00\x03A T?\x80\x00\x00>B\x8f\\>B\x8f\\\x00\x05Swift\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\xb8\x00\x00
```

I understand its a bit of a long shot, but im trying to understand exactly how java packs a ByteBuffer object into a sqlite database, and subsequently to read the data natively, be able to edit the data natively in Python (3), and then save it back to the original format so that the original ByteBuffer can be reloaded by the native java class.

Probably completely crazy but if anyone fancies giving it a whirl with me, I would love your help :)

EDIT:

what have i tried so far?

mainly the obvious, like:

```
data.decode('utf8')
data.decode(...several encodings...)
bytearray(data).decode(...several encodings...)
```

PyByteBuffer

```
from PyByteBuffer import ByteBuffer
bb = ByteBuffer()
bb.wrap(data)
```

essentially produces the same output.

Cyberchef:

Tried the magic function and many different encoding types, from hex dump, etc. Really threw everything at it with no results.

What loads this BLOB in Java code?

```
public void load(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int worldId) throws IOException {
     int byteBufferOffset = byteBuffer.getInt();
     this.chr.Traits.clear();

     int traitOffset;
     for(traitOffset = 0; traitOffset < byteBufferOffset; ++traitOffset) {
        String traitName = GameWindow.ReadString(byteBuffer);
        if (TraitFactory.getTrait(traitName) != null) {
           if (!this.chr.Traits.contains(traitName)) {
              this.chr.Traits.add(traitName);
           }
        } else {
           DebugLog.General.error("unknown trait \"" + traitName + "\"");
        }
     }

     this.TotalXP = byteBuffer.getFloat();
     this.level = byteBuffer.getInt();
     this.lastlevel = byteBuffer.getInt();
     this.XPMap.clear();
     traitOffset = byteBuffer.getInt();

     int perkOffset;
     for(perkOffset = 0; perkOffset < traitOffset; ++perkOffset) {
        PerkFactory.Perk perk = this.loadPerk(byteBuffer, worldId);
        float perkExperience = byteBuffer.getFloat();
        if (perk != null) {
           this.XPMap.put(perk, perkExperience);
        }
     }

     int perkCounter;
     if (worldId < 162) {
        perkOffset = byteBuffer.getInt();

        for(perkCounter = 0; perkCounter < perkOffset; ++perkCounter) {
           this.loadPerk(byteBuffer, worldId);
        }
     }

     IsoGameCharacter.this.PerkList.clear();
     perkOffset = byteBuffer.getInt();

     for(perkCounter = 0; perkCounter < perkOffset; ++perkCounter) {
        PerkFactory.Perk perk2 = this.loadPerk(byteBuffer, worldId);
        int perkLevel = byteBuffer.getInt();
        if (perk2 != null) {
           IsoGameCharacter.PerkInfo perkInfo = IsoGameCharacter.this.new PerkInfo();
           perkInfo.perk = perk2;
           perkInfo.level = perkLevel;
           IsoGameCharacter.this.PerkList.add(perkInfo);
        }
     }

     perkCounter = byteBuffer.getInt();

     for(int perkXpMultiplierOffset = 0; perkXpMultiplierOffset < perkCounter; ++perkXpMultiplierOffset) {
        PerkFactory.Perk multiplierPerk = this.loadPerk(byteBuffer, worldId);
        float perkXpMultiplier = byteBuffer.getFloat();
        byte perkMinLevel = byteBuffer.get();
        byte perMaxLevel = byteBuffer.get();
        if (multiplierPerk != null) {
           this.addXpMultiplier(multiplierPerk, perkXpMultiplier, perkMinLevel, perMaxLevel);
        }
     }

     if (this.TotalXP > (float)IsoGameCharacter.this.getXpForLevel(this.getLevel() + 1)) {
        this.setTotalXP((float)this.chr.getXpForLevel(this.getLevel()));
     }

     this.recalcSumm();
  }
```

Comment: Looks like that's a bunch of escaped bytes, which you should be able to read into Python and decode as actual bytes without any issue that I can foresee. As far as what the data represents, that's a whole other issue but you haven't mentioned that so I figure you have that covered.

Comment: will update with what i have tried sorry

Comment: As for what the data represents, its absolutely a BinaryStream of some description as such that can be used with Java classes

Comment: If we had the original code that creates this data we'd have a shot at telling you what it is.  The answer to "how Java packs a byte buffer into SQLite" is "any way it wants."

Comment: I can give you the original way with a little it of reverse engineering, but i dont understand how that will help, its how it saves a blob, regardless of how interprets it on either end